# Posses vs possession

Tags: vocabulary

Is it better "I have something in my posses" or "I have something in my possession"? or are both OK?
The first *poss*ibility sounds a little more hi-brow to me...

---

PS, I'm not confident of the tag I've chosen, feel free to edit

Comment: Do you mean "possess?" What do the dictionary entries for each word suggest to you?

Comment: Why do you need more than one posse, and wouldn't it be "*someone* in my posses"?

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is the correct one. Possession is a noun, whereas possess is a verb and the noun is what you are looking for here.

According to Merriam Webster, the definition of the word **possession** is as follows:

> the act of having or taking into control

or

> something owned, occupied, or controlled

Here's the link: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/possession?src=search-dict-hed

Answer (score -1):

The first usage is not correct. To posses is an action, posses is a verb. Something that I do posses is my possession, at least for now. The second sentence is correct, "I have something in my possession."

Comment: The verb is possess, not posses. Posses means several groups of armed men under a sheriff.

Comment: Guilty! I went with the spell check. Take me away.

Comment: I won't take you away, I'll send the posses!